# Symfony2 & IvoryGoogleMapsBundle - Unrecognized option “api_key” under “ivory_google_map”

Tags: google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3, config, api-key

I have installed `IvoryGoogleMapsBundle` as described in documentation using Composer.

```
$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle
$ composer require php-http/httplug-bundle
```

I registered bundles in `AppKernel` class:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Ivory\GoogleMapBundle\IvoryGoogleMapBundle(),
        new Http\HttplugBundle\HttplugBundle()
    );
```

And in config file I descriped api_key as shown in documentation [here](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/map.md#api-key):

```
ivory_google_map:
    api_key: "%my_key%"
```

So the problem is that I get an error:

```
Unrecognized option "api_key" under "ivory_google_map"
```

But when I am not describing `api_key` in config I get `MissingKeyMapError` in browser console.

Btw, Bundle does not have `ApiHelperBuilder` Class and I cannot set `api_key` in controller.

Symfony version: 2.8, IvoryGoogleMapsBundle version: ^2.2

Any ideas what I could be missing that documentation does not mention?

```
----------
  UPDATE
----------
```

I just read bundle creators comment [here](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/issues/176#issuecomment-246431610) on the issue @Matteo linked me in comment section below. Occurs that in `dev-master` documentation, that I was following, the installation of bundle is not working properly... Running `$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle` installs `2.2.1` version of Bundle which does not support `api_key`.

Unfortunatelly I cannot find a way to install `dev-master` version. `$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master` does not work. It suggests `^2.0@dev` version which does not support `api_key` either. How do I install `dev-master` version?

Comment: have you activated the bundle in `app/Appkernel.php` ?

Comment: Yes I registered bundle in AppKernel. When I set `geocoder` in `ivory_google_maps` it does not throw error. It is just that I cannot add `api_key`, `debug` or `language` inside as it is in documentation.

Comment: I updated question so you could see how I registered in AppKernel.

Comment: have you see this issue https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/issues/176 ?

Comment: @Matteo okay so [here](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/issues/176#issuecomment-246431610) is a possible solution answered by Egeloen. Anyway, he said that documentation I am looking at is for dev-master. I tried installing it in composer "dev-master", but I get error that this version does not exist I should use "^2.0@dev", but unfortunately that version does not support api_key either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end composer was downloading wrong version. It had to download `dev-master`, but since in my composer.json `minimum-stability` is set to `stable` it was downloading latest stable version `^2.2`. To define `minimum-stability` for single package I had to modify `composer.json`:

```
...
"egeloen/google-map": "^2.0@dev",
"egeloen/google-map-bundle": "dev-master",
...
```

Now since I have dev-master version downloaded, `api_key` under `ivory_google_maps` is working fine.